# Ng grid row position changed in grouping when used cell template in angularJs

Tags: css, angularjs, ng-grid

I have tried to add grouping capability to ng grid and its working fine.But the problem was that when i expand group row(arrow icon)it will mess css styles and there was a lotof gap between arrow icon and  row content .so it will waste lot of spaces.i have tried to overcome that problem but couldn't find any solution.please let me know how to solve this.

(Note:I have figured it out gap = rowHeight in gridOptions.because i have set height for grid)

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
data: 'restData',
rowHeight: 245,
enablePinning: true,
columnDefs: [{
  field: 'testPlan',
  displayName: '',
  cellTemplate: template
}
```

[Sample code in plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/zaeyxANdyPPevUaggBTj?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figured it out what was the reason.Becasue default row height is 30px and according to that value they organize CSS.so i have to removed `.ngAggregate` attribute from CSS and modified the following CSS attributes according to my requirement.

```
.ngAggArrowExpanded {
    position: relative;
    left: -10px;
    top: -14px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 0 9px 9px;
    border-color: transparent transparent #000 transparent
}
.ngAggArrowCollapsed {
    position: relative;
    left: -10px;
    top: -14px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px 0 5px 8.7px;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #000
}
```